# Interaction between models and controller in rails 3 with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sti

I am implementing a web solution with rails 3 where a user has a list of "Actions". They can either be pending or validated and only an admin can validate.

Two typical actions would be:

1/ Reporting an incorrect picture (if the admin validates then the picture will be deleted hence we need its id)
2/ Submitting a new category (if the admin validates then the category will be added)

Each action has a specific number of point that will go toward the user's reputation which, t me, makes it a good candidate for inheritance (shared behavior at the end of the validation, specific fields and method implementation in the children).

I was planning to have a "onValidate" method in the model that would either delete the picture (1/) or add a new category (2/) but it feels weird to put that in the model.

Can you please let me know how to enhance that design and move that in the controller(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are describing correctly, I don't understand why you think having this code in the model is a bad thing. I take it your User has_many Actions, and an Action has a score.  When an action is validated, the state of some other object changes (a picture is deleted, a category is added')

```
class DeletePictureAction < Action
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :picture

  def on_validate
     do_subclass_specific_stuff_to(picture)
     add_to_user_score(score)
  end
end
```

Nothing here seems to be anything to do with routing and so it has no place in the controller ...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for ("Nothing here seems to be anything to do with routing and so it has no place in the controller").